# Why might these values not be uniq'ed together?

Tags: text-processing, uniq

I am trying to figure out which IP addresses hit the server most often. I received this surprising output from `uniq`:

```
$ cat access_log | awk '{print $1}' | uniq -c | sort -bnr | head
 26 73.23.5.25
 25 73.23.5.25
 24 73.23.5.25
 23 73.23.5.25
 23 73.23.5.25
 23 73.23.5.25
 22 73.23.5.25
 21 73.23.5.25
 19 73.23.5.25
 18 73.23.5.25
```

Why might these addresses not be considered the same address by `uniq`? I have looked at the source file and there are no crazy tabs or other whitespace. These are fairly common Apache access logs.

Comment: Are the non-unique lines always adjacent? If not, you likely need an additional `sort` _before_ the `uniq -c`

Comment: @steeldriver: that was it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

EDIT: you need to sort BEFORE running uniq, otherwise it won't work:

```
cat access_log | awk '{print $1}' | sort | uniq -c | sort -bnr | head
```

Comment: @garethTheRed yes, I realized and changed the answer. I'm used to see `uniq` at the end of pipelines so I didn't notice right away